# C: "Access Violation" error on runtime

Tags: c, pointers, access-violation

Please look at my code:

```
adj = (int *)calloc(n * n, sizeof(int));

scanf("%d", &m);

for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    scanf("%d %d %d", &x, &y, &w);
    adjSetter(x - 1, y - 1, w);
    adjSetter(y - 1, x - 1, w);
}
```

This part is in the main function and adjSetter is as below:

```
void adjSetter(int i, int j, int value) {
    *(adj + (i * n + j) * sizeof(int)) = value;
}
```

Now the problem is when adjSetter function is called with i more than 2500 then I will get an Access Violation error. What's wrong with my code?

P.S.: n is 10000

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: You have some undeclared variables. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `* sizeof(int)` Hmmm, this smells. Learn about pointer aritimetics.

Comment: Not testing the return value from scanf is always asking for surprises.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `i = 2500, n = 10000, j = 0, sizeof(int) = 4`, `(i * n + j) * sizeof(int)` will become `100000000`.

`*(adj + (i * n + j) * sizeof(int))` is equivalent to `adj[(i * n + j) * sizeof(int)]`, so accessing `adj[100000000]` will cause out-of-range access, which invokes *undefined behavior* if only 100000000 elements are allocated via `adj = (int *)calloc(n * n, sizeof(int));`.

To fix this problem, remove the harmful `* sizeof(int)` so that it can access the elements of the array properly.

```
void adjSetter(int i, int j, int value) {
    *(adj + (i * n + j)) = value;
}
```

Better thing is to use array indexing, which I think is more easy-to-read and write.

```
void adjSetter(int i, int j, int value) {
    adj[i * n + j] = value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this is an algorithm for an ACM-Competition-Like homework. So these are the assignment constraints. And I don't know what to do ?!

Comment: What is "these"? causing out-of-range access?

Comment: just remove the `sizeof int`, it's simply wrong there

Comment: That was true, I have to remove that **sizeof(int)**. Thanks all

Comment: @MikeCAT Please edit your answer to emphasize on removing that sizeof(int), which solved my problem. Thanks a lot.